# Is an uncocked semi-automatic with ammo in the clip considered “loaded”?

Tags: firearms

A semi-automatic must be racked, to put a round in the firing chamber, before it can be fired.

Is there a legal definition of “loaded” that considers option 2 of the following states of loadedness as not being “loaded”?

1. Empty
2. Ammo in the clip, but not in the chamber (pulling the trigger would do nothing)
3. A round in the chamber, safety on
4. Ready to fire (safety off)

Obviously option 2 is not relevant to a revolver, which only requires a trigger pull to bring the next round in front of the firing pin.

Comment: I'd say that the common meaning of the term includes all of 2-4.  But if you want to know about a legal definition, you'll have to specify a jurisdiction (country, state, etc) and ideally a specific law (the term could be used differently in different sections of the law).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about firearm nomenclature not law. Try asking on English stack exchange.

Comment: I'm not sure it's off-topic.  English usage is that a gun is loaded if there's bullets in it.  The question is whether there's a legal definition somewhere that is less inclusive.  Laws sometimes come with definitions to allow the body of the law to be concise but still have a well-determined meaning.

Comment: Perhaps “armed” better describes 3 and 4, and “loaded” 2, 3 and 4. Perhaps the question is better answered from the “gun community” (but AFAIK there isn’t such a stack exchange site).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your jurisdiction.  Check the applicable laws; there's probably a section named something like "definitions" that gives the meaning of terms such as "loaded".  For example, from [RCW 9.41.010](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9.41.010) (the "Terms defined" section of the "Firearms and Dangerous Weapons" chapter of the Washington State laws):

> (17) "Loaded" means:
>
> (a) There is a cartridge in the chamber of the firearm;
>
> (b) Cartridges are in a clip that is locked in place in the firearm;
>
> (c) There is a cartridge in the cylinder of the firearm, if the firearm is a revolver;
>
> (d) There is a cartridge in the tube or magazine that is inserted in the action; or
>
> (e) There is a ball in the barrel and the firearm is capped or primed if the firearm is a muzzle loader.

So in Washington State, any of your examples 2-4 would be considered "loaded" for the purposes of firearms-related crimes.

Comment: As it happens, Washington state was where I lived for a while, and where I may live again one day, and thus the jurisdiction I was most interested in.

Comment: Note that this is a fairly intuitive definition of "loaded" - in Ohio, for instance, a gun is unloaded if ["...(2) Any magazine or speed loader that contains ammunition and that may be used with the firearm in question is stored in a compartment within the vehicle in question that cannot be accessed without leaving the vehicle or is stored in a container that provides complete and separate enclosure."](http://ohiogunlawyer.com/motor-vehicle-carry-laws/), which basically means a gun is loaded for the purposes of the law if the means to load it is just in the same container as the gun.